# Laravel PhpUnit 'Undefined variable: errors'

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

I try to use PhpUnit with Laravel 5.2.

When I run this test:

```
 class TestInscription extends TestCase
{
    
    
    /******************************************************************************/
    /* pour lancer le test : C:\wamp\www\compet>phpunit tests/TestInscription.php */
    /******************************************************************************/
    
    
    
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        
    }
    
    public function testInscriptionAvecErreur()
    {
        $this->visit('inscription')
        ->seePageIs('inscription')
        ->see('Inscription')
        ->type('', 'nom')
        ->type('', 'prenom')
        ->type('', 'email')
        ->type('', 'password')
        ->type('', 'password_confirm')
        ->press('bouton_valider')
        ->seePageIs('inscription')
        ->see('Nom obligatoire')
        ->see('Prénom obligatoire')
        ->see('Adresse email obligatoire')
        ->see('Mot de passe obligatoire');
        
    }
```

I have a response "OK".

When I add a second test into the same class, like this :

```
 class TestInscription extends TestCase
{
    
    
    /******************************************************************************/
    /* pour lancer le test : C:\wamp\www\compet>phpunit tests/TestInscription.php */
    /******************************************************************************/
    
    
    
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        
    }
    
    public function testInscriptionAvecErreur()
    {
        $this->visit('inscription')
        ->seePageIs('inscription')
        ->see('Inscription')
        ->type('', 'nom')
        ->type('', 'prenom')
        ->type('', 'email')
        ->type('', 'password')
        ->type('', 'password_confirm')
        ->press('bouton_valider')
        ->seePageIs('inscription')
        ->see('Nom obligatoire')
        ->see('Prénom obligatoire')
        ->see('Adresse email obligatoire')
        ->see('Mot de passe obligatoire');
        
    }
    
    
    public function testInscriptionAvecErreurMdp()
    {
        $this->visit('inscription')
        ->seePageIs('inscription')
        ->see('Inscription')
        ->type('azerty', 'password')
        ->type('azertyu', 'password_confirm')
        ->press('bouton_valider')
        ->seePageIs('inscription')
        ->see('Les 2 mots de passe sont différents');
        
    }
    

}
```

then I have an error on the first test (the second one is not triggered). The error is:

```
    Time: 2.69 seconds, Memory: 20.50MB

There was 1 failure:

1) TestInscription::testInscriptionAvecErreur
A request to [http://localhost/inscription] failed. Received status code [500].

C:\wamp\www\compet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:196
C:\wamp\www\compet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:80
C:\wamp\www\compet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:61
C:\wamp\www\compet\tests\TestInscription.php:21
C:\wamp\www\ecole\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:149
C:\wamp\www\ecole\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:100

Caused by
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: errors' in C:\wamp\www\compet\storage\framework\views\7a56ba5973bcafaa00c3a5edb3816871f0ac8a17.php:44
```

I see in this view:

```
<div class="form-group <?php echo e($errors->has('nom') ? 'has-error has-feedback' : ''); ?>">
```

Certainly the error is because this variable "$errors", but what?

and why the first test runs fine when it is alone. And fails when I add a second test?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error (but don't know if it is the real reason).

When I create several functions into my class, then I have the error. When I create only 1 function into my class, then I have no errors.

So I decided to create only 1 function per test class (even if the function can be very long).